# How do i exclude some elements of a list from further calculations

Tags: python-3.7

So I have a list of stars and their respective distances. My assignment is to find which stars are in a certain distance (+- 10parsec). I want to **exclude** some of them **from further calculations** in the program. The thing is I **don't want to remove** them completely so `remove`, `pop` etc isn't helping me. I still want those stars on the list to be present in my output csv. I just want a line saying something like *those stars which don't support the `if` statement, don't use them in this calculation*. So i guess the output would be blank for those.

I suppose it is an if or for statement, to mark those bad stars as *False* and then down the line use calculation that excludes those faulty stars.

I'm a physics student and this is my first python program ever! Please be cool about my ignorance...

**Edit**: forgive me if i include useless stuff i don't really know what's important. I also use uncertainties library if its of any use

```
column_names = ['id','pi','s_pi','v_r' ,'s_v', 'dis', 'X', 
            'ra_h', 'ra_m', 'ra_s','dec_d', 'dec_m', 
            'dec_s', 'ma', 's_ma', 'md', 's_md']


data = pd.read_csv("hyades_data.dat", skiprows=2, sep='\s+', 
names=column_names)

calculations with all

v_r = unumpy.uarray(data['v_r'], data['s_v'])
ma = unumpy.uarray(data['ma'], data['s_ma'])
md = unumpy.uarray(data['md'], data['s_md'])
mi = unumpy.sqrt(ma**2+md**2)
r_m = v_r*unumpy.tan(th)/(4.74*mi/1000)


diff = np.abs(r_pc - r_m)
'''
if np.abs(dist-46.43) <=10:
    r_m=True
else r_m=False

at this point i want to make the distiction
'''

mean_diff = diff.mean()

print("Mean : ")
print(mean_diff)
print(a_ref,d_ref)


df_va=pd.DataFrame(v_r)
df_mi = pd.DataFrame(mi)
df_rm = pd.DataFrame(r_m)
df_rpc = pd.DataFrame(r_pc)
df_diff = pd.DataFrame(diff)
#df_mean_diff = pd.DataFrame(mean_diff)
ve = v_r*np.tan(th)

output = pd.concat([data['id'], ra, dec, th_d, df_mi, df_rm, df_rpc, 
df_diff,df_va], axis=1)
output.columns = ['id','ra', 'dec', 'th_d','mi', 'r_m', 'r_pc', 
'dist_diff','va']
output.to_csv('results.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Add some code for us to see where you got stuck then we can help you .

Comment: Use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) or equivalent list comprehension.

Comment: please share how the list you are working with looks like.